# How can C print a super-large number?

Tags: c, linux, windows, gcc, compilation

How can this code print such a large number? I have tried it on Ubuntu 14.04 (gcc 4.8.2).
It does not work the same on MS Windows with any compiler (even MinGW, which is called "gcc for Windows"). Why?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int main()
{
    printf("%.0f\n",pow(2,500));
}
```

Ubuntu output:

```
3273390607896141870013189696827599152216642046043064789483291368096133796404
674554883270092325904157150886684127560071009217256545885393053328527589376
```

Windows output:

```
3273390607896141900000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

<sup>(The line break is added for clarity only.)</sup>

Comment: Perhaps GCC used its dependency, [MPFR](http://www.mpfr.org/), to evaluate the floating-point expression to arbitrary precision, given that it is a constant?

Comment: cast to some certain type like (long double)pow(2,500) and the difference should disappear

Comment: does printf("%.0lf\n",power(2,500)); do something different?

Answer (score 7):

As hinted by OP and commented by @user300234,  `2^500` is a 501 bit number, but that is not the issue here.

`pow(2,500)` returns a `double`, about `3.27e150`, which is typically a [binary64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format).  This type supports about 15 - 17 decimal digits of precision.  So for numbers *near* `3.27e150`, printing more that 17 digits of significance is usually not important.  It is well smaller than `DBL_MAX` which may be about `1.798e308`.

The trick here is that `pow(2,500)` is *exactly* representable as a floating point `double` (binary64).  This may give the illusion that a `double` has hundreds of bits of precision - it does not.

The 2 different compilations handle conversion of `double` to text in different ways, once 17 or so digits are printed - this is allowable by the C spec.  The minimum number of correct digits is `DBL_DECIMAL_DIG` - likely 17 on both systems.

Consider printing the *next* greater `double`.  Although the next double could be printed with 150 or so digits, typically these additional digits way pass `DBL_DECIMAL_DIG` are simply noise for many applications.

```
// 2 ^ 500
327339060789614 187001318969682759915221664...
// next
327339060789614 259685191399243448970154045...
```

Comment: 2^500 can be _EXACTLY_ represented by 500 bits, not 501 : https://www.google.com/search?q=ln(2%5E500)+%2F+ln(2)

Comment: @specializt  `2^3` is `8`in decimal or `1000` in binary which is 4 binary digits and not 3.  `2^500` would take 501 binary digits to express.

Comment: well alright : 2^8 can be represented with 3 bits - simply remove the digit 0 from your data-word and shift everything "to the right", meaning binary 001 will be decimal 2 instead of decimal 1 (and binary 000 will be  decimal 1) - thats a common encoding in industrial messaging protocols, for example - the digit 0 has to be transferred / signalled seperately. This encoding is equal to the real amount of binary information in a digit, it is highly useful for high-frequency data transmissions whereas each value has a rather small range (16-32 bits mostly)

Comment: @specializt, I'm afraid this is not as you think.  Even if you select an algorithm that allows you to represent 2^n with only n bits, to represent an unsigned integer with n bits allows you to represent numbers from 0 to 2^n-1 only.  This leaves outside the number 2^n as the first candidate to enter in the club when you use n+1 bits.  If you are using a protocol that forbids the use of 0 as a proper value, then you can use these tricks, but that doesn't make it false that 2^n is a binary numer of n+1 binary digits.

Answer (score 4):

The Microsoft Visual C Run-Time Library (`msvcrt.dll`), also used by MinGW, only supports up to 17 digits of precision, since this is enough to uniquely identify a (IEEE 754) `double`.

But good news: your code compiled with VS2015 CTP4 produces the same output as your Ubuntu example. And if you're using MinGW-w64, you can define `__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO` as `1` before including `<stdio.h>` or via `-D` compiler option for the same output.

Comment: what is msvcrt.dll ? how does VS2015 CTP4 produces diff output ? how does ubuntu produces output ?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a new answer, but a slightly different spin on what others have already said:

The difference is not in the `pow()` function:  The difference is in the `printf()` function.  Ubuntu printf() is printing the exact decimal value of `pow(2,500)`.  The Windows printf() is printing an approximation that is correct to 17 decimal digits.

Both implementations are, in some sense, correct; but I would say that the Windows printf() is *more* correct.  Here's why:

**If you care about more than 17 digits of precision, then you should not be using `double`.**

In general, the result of *most* double computations is only correct in the first 17 digits.  (`pow(2, n)` is a very special case where the answer is exactly correct for any *n* in range.)  By printing the exact decimal value of very large doubles, the Ubuntu library is fooling you;  Suppose you have

```
double a = ...;
double b = ...;
double c = a*b;

printf("%f", c);
```

You don't want to know the exact value of `c` because, for most `a` and `b`, `c` is *not equal* to `a*b`:  It's only an *approximation* of a*b--an approximation that's accurate to about 17 significant digits.

If you need more than 17 digits of precision, then you should be using an extended-precision math library like GMP (https://gmplib.org/)